# Maplex label engine

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, maplex

I'm currently going through the GIS 20 essential skills book where I have to fix labels. I have changed the setting from simple to Maplex and now I couldn't figure out how to assign buffers to label using conflict detection tab in Maplex. Usually, I would assign "2" to a simple label. So how do I do that in Maplex? It has two choices; Interior boundary features and exterior boundary features. I tried entering the same for Maplex but the results are still chaos.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the maplex labelling engine is enabled.

> When a label buffer is specified, the Maplex Label Engine uses this
>   buffer as a guide for the trial positions and places the labels with
>   their buffer if there is space available. If creating a buffer for a
>   label would result in unplaced labels, the label engine will not
>   create the buffer, resulting in closely placed labels. In this
>   situation, no labels will be dropped from placement.
>
> If the **Hard constraint** check box is checked, the buffer is respected
>   regardless of available space. This results in well-spaced labels but
>   also in the possibility of many unplaced labels.

key part is to modify the label buffer value as a percentage of font height. The default is **15%, and the maximum is 50%**.

full detials
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-text/specifying-a-label-buffer-distance-to-change-the-s.htm